# codeigniter3 form validation callback function calls unnecessarily

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter 3.I have a email field in form and using `required|callback_is_email_exist rules` on email.**When I leave email field blank,it shows callback message instead of required message**.
I had worked on codeigniter 2 ,it perefctly shows "required" message, CI3 form validation not executing rules in the sequence when callbacks are used.
Following is my code

---

**View : welcome_message**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Welcome to CodeIgniter</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

    <?php echo form_open('Welcome'); ?>

    <h5>Username</h5>

    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" size="50" />

    <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

---

**Controller:welcome.php**

```
public function index()
    {
         $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));


        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|callback_is_email_exist');

                if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
                {
                     $this->load->view('welcome_message');
                }
                else
                {
                        echo 'success';
                }
    }

         public function is_email_exist($str)
        {
            //  code to check email exist in databse here
                if (is_email_exist($str)
                {
                      return TRUE;  
                }
                else
                { 
                $this->form_validation->set_message('is_email_exist', 'Email Does not exist');
                            return FALSE;
                    }
            }
```

---

**Expected Output**

*email filed is required*

---

Codeingiter 3 expects to execute rule in sequence.If one succeeds then next one executes.In this case if I leave email field blank it executes callback unnecessarily.Thus it shows wrong message.It should display email field is required instead of email does not exist.

Appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it so:

Create file: /application/libraries/MY_form_validation.php

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) {
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
}
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Your custom validation
     */
    public function is_email_exist($str)
        {
            $CI =& get_instance();
            //  code to check email exist in databse here
            if ($str=='test') {
                return true;  
            }else { 
                $this->form_validation->set_message('is_email_exist', 'Email Does not exist');
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
}

/* End of file MY_form_validation.php */

/* Location: ./application/libraries/MY_form_validation.php */
```

In controller (remove callback):

```
...
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|is_email_exist');
...
```

In controller remove function: `callback_is_email_exist`.

But If you want to check if the email is unique to do so:

In controller:

```
...
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]',['is_unique'=>'Email exist!']);
...
```

Comment: Thanks creating putting callback code in MY_form_validation has worked for me :)